# d3.js - Create a population pyramid

Tags: d3.js

I want to create a population pyramid and animate this with d3.js like in this example http://populationpyramid.net/world/

I'm new to d3.js and I try to figure out how to start. So far I found the Stack layout as a possibility https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout

But I didn't figure out how to change the orientation axis to display it vertically instead of horizontally. How is that possible? Or is there another way to achive this with a different approach?

Thanks for reading!

Bernhard

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make D3 Streamgraph vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018259/how-to-make-d3-streamgraph-vertically)

Comment: On a different note, I'm not sure if a stacked layout is the best choice for a population pyramid. [Here](http://vis.stanford.edu/jheer/d3/pyramid/shift.html) is an example in D3 that uses bars.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the answer is in this other question you mentioned. I try it with bars as well, see which looks better.